# WearOS app:boxedEdges="all" hides the scrollbars in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, wear-os

Does anyone have a work around?

The scrolls bars are visible without `boxed edges`

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

But as soon as I add the boxed edges `app:boxedEdges="all"`, the scrollbar completely disappears. Not sure why. Does anyone have a workaround or another solution?

It's a big issue because WearOS policy now rejects all apps immediately if a scrollable view (RecyclerView, ScrollView) does not have scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Try to use the [WearableRecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/widget/WearableRecyclerView) instead of the regular RecyclerView;

2 - Do you really need the "boxedEdges"? In case you do, can't you added it to a container instead of the element itself? Or get a work-around for the design?

3 - I don't know if it will do any changes, but I like to add the "android:orientation="vertical" parameter along with the scrollbar...

Comment: Yes I've tried it with ```WearableRecyclerView``` and it doesn't work. I need the ```boxedEdges``` because the root view is ```BoxInsetLayout```. The hacky solution that I got it working is adding a padding of ```32dp```.